# ASP.NET Dynamical Creating Custom Control

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I created user control and want to add it to page. I use next code:

```
Controls_MultiTextInput cc = new Controls_MultiTextInput();
Controls.Add(cc);
```

But control doesn't appear on page. What is wrong?

Comment: I am able to add control using this.Controls.Add(this.LoadControl("MultiTextInput.ascx"));

But it seems  a bad way, because I was not able to set properties of control before adding.

Comment: Does it work when you add a non-custom control, eg a TextBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.Controls.Add(this.LoadControl("MultiTextInput.ascx"))` is the correct way to load the control because it needs to know where the ascx file is.

If you want to set properties, do this:

```
Controls_MultiTextInput cc = (Controls_MultiTextInput) LoadControl("MultiTextInput.ascx");
cc.MyProperty = "abc";
Controls.Add(cc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Anton you can set properties !

```
Controls_MultiTextInput cc 
   = (Controls_MultiTextInpu)Page.LoadControl("MultiTextInput.ascx");

cc.variable = 2;
cc.SetProperties(223,2311);

Controls.Add(cc);

or

PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(cc);
```